# System defaults?

Tags: swift, macos

I'm writing an app in Swift for macOS.  I will be using the `UserDefaults` API to save a bunch of parameters on a user-by-user basis.  I'm looking for a similar place to save license data, so that once a license is granted, all users on the device can share that license.

(This app was originally written in Java, and I'm reimplementing it in Swift.  The old app used `Preferences.userRoot()` for the user data and `Preferences.systemRoot()` for the license data.  What is the analagous structure in macOS?)

Comment: If your app is sandboxed, any folder that it is not in your App's sandbox you would need to present open/save panel to let the user select the location

Comment: What's the point of sandboxing an app when Apple doesn't even allow you to require your application to have a license key?

Answer (score 0):

License data should be saved - by convention - in `~/Library/Application Support`, which usually contains all app-specific data.

From the [Library Directory Details document](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/MacOSXDirectories/MacOSXDirectories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH10-SW1):

> Contains all app-specific data and support files. These are the files that your app creates and manages on behalf of the user and can include files that contain user data.
>
> By convention, all of these items should be put in a subdirectory whose name matches the bundle identifier of the app. For example, if your app is named MyApp and has the bundle identifier com.example.MyApp, you would put your app’s user-specific data files and resources in the ~/Library/Application Support/com.example.MyApp/ directory. Your app is responsible for creating this directory as needed.
>
> Resources required by the app to run must be placed inside the app bundle itself.

Comment: I'm fine with `~/Library`.  How do I get write access to `/Library`?

Comment: Is the app sandboxed?

Comment: Yes, it's sandboxed.  I haven't tried accessing `/Library` programmatically, but bash won't let me write to `/Library` without using `sudo`.

Comment: @JerryAgin that's the system-wide `Library` folder - `~/Library` is the user one.